# Use {{Variable}} inside {{#each}}?

Tags: zurb-foundation

im using foundation 6.4 and I want to use a partial and fill it with data from my data.yml via each helper.

The partial shall be used on multiple pages and I would like to use the front matter to inject the correct source for the each, like so:

Partial:

```
<div class="callout text-center">
  <h2>Become A Member</h2>

      {{#each source}}
      <div class="floated-label-wrapper">
        <label for="full-name">{{label}}</label>
        <input type="text" id={{id}} name={{name}} placeholder={{placeholder}}>
      </div>
      {{/each}}

      <button class="button expanded" id="submitUserDataButton">Sign up</button>

</div>
```

Page:

```
---
registration: true
source: data.stuff
---

{{> floated-label-wrapper}}
```

However, when I insert the variable like above, nothing happens. 
When I nest the handlebar syntax inside the each helper like so

```
{{#each {{source}}}}
```

I get an error that parsing failed.
Is it actually possible to use the handlebar variables inside of a handlebar helper?

Answer (score 0):

You are really close! Say our data is in registrations.yml which lives in the assets/data folder.
(make sure you do not use .yaml -- just .yml) 
Variable are 
firstname: Bill
lastname: Booth
On your Page: 
`{{#each registrations}}  //do not add .yml//
<ul>
<li>{{firstname}} {{lastname}}</li>
<ul>
{{/each}}`

For all your data, you will get a list line.  //Bill Booth//